# Why .zip is not being created by azure devops for specific webjob project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs

I have 3 webjob projects on my application

Webjob A, B, and C

When running visual studio ci/cd I got this error on release for Webjob.A project

### [error]Error: No package found with specified pattern:

After some investigation I found out that zip files were created for webjob.B and webjob.C but not for webjob.A during publishing artefact.

Anyone have idea what the problem is?

Comment: Could you please share your build pipeline, and also more error message(`No package found with specified pattern`: what is the pattern?). The detailed configuration of the tasks in your pipeline need to be checked for troubleshooting this kind of issue.

Comment: I have found the problem, it turned out I needed to add this line in the webjob csproj <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.9\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.9\tools\webjobs.targets')" />

Comment: You can accept it as answer to help others who have same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary your comment to here to help others who have same issue.

Add the following line in webjob's .csproj file.

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.9\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.9\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
```